# Is it safe to send the username to a custom handler?

Tags: asp.net-core, razor-pages

I am using ASP.NET Core Razor, which has this custom handler.

```
public JsonResult OnPostSaveMyStuff(string username, string myStuff)
{
    ...
}
```

When a logged-in member clicks a button, an ajax request will be made to call that method. The anti-forgery token will also be sent.

I would like to know whether sending the username via ajax is safe. Would a bad actor who logged into his own account and then changed the username behind the scenes

If this is not safe, what should I Google to learn about the secure way?

Comment: As you suspect, it is incorrect to trust this username.  You don't need a hacker.  A legitimate user may use its own CSRF token and post things under a different username.  CSRF tokens are there to prevent a different attack.  They are no good to "certify" the correctness of the data in the request.  What you need is something like a JWT, whose digital signature certifies whatever is inside the token's payload, which usually includes a user identifier.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you send any data to your application over the wire, it becomes user input and is prone to tampering. In the case of a user name, it is not necessary to explicitly send this as part of a request. It is already being sent in an encrypted cookie to prevent tampering. Authentication middleware hydrates this into an instance of `ClaimsPrincipal` which is then available within your `PageModel` via its `User` property:

```
var username = User.Identity.Name;
```

Comment: I'm using Individual Account rather than Microsoft Identity. Any way I can set the value?

Comment: You can create a `ClaimsPrincipal` when you authenticate your user and pass it to the `HttpContext.SigninAsync` method, which results in the authentication cookie being created: https://www.mikesdotnetting.com/article/335/simple-authentication-in-razor-pages-without-a-database. Check the Creating The Login Form section for an example.